# Install all the site packages of Django rest framework project at once

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gitignore, site-packages

I have git-ignored venv/ of the Django rest framework project.(According to a git ignore file of a tutorial)
Now the other users of the repository needs a way to install the site-packages that I use in my local pc.
I want a command or way to install the same site-packages in other's pc's. And where are those site-packages are listed as a file?

Comment: You should have been building such a file yourself as you worked, e.g. in a `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: So, Pipfile is just like a note? Or can I use that file to install those packages as command using pip install or something like that?

Comment: No, those files aren't just notes. They can be used to install dependencies with different tools. Read the proposed duplicate I gave, then search for "python dependency management".

Comment: I am not aware about the virtualenv. Can you tell me about that?

Comment: We're not here to replace documentation. Please search for "python virtualenv" and go from there.

Comment: I refered your link. I think it is helpful. I appreciate your help.